# moving text over an image, without the image moving

Tags: css

I have a banner that I am trying to add a text to the bottom portion of it. I got the text centered and how I want to be, but when I want to move the text to the bottom of the page, the picture moves too.

HTML

```
<div class="col_one art-banner">
        <div class="art-banner-text">
            <h2>what do <span>you</span> want to learn?</h2>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.art-banner { background-image: url("graphics/art_banner.jpg"); height: 150px;}
.art-banner-text { width: 940px; height: 50px; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); }
.art-banner-text h2 { text-align: center; padding-top: 10px; font-family: "Bender";}
.art-banner-text span { color: #eb6623; }
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ryrnxz7/)

Comment: How are you moving the text to the bottom?

Comment: @putvande I tried margin-top, padding-top, top: -100px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming you're trying to use `margin-top` to move the art-banner-text down, you're running into the collapsing margin problem: the margin is shared between the inner div and the outer one, meaning the outer one gets the margin too.

So the solution is not to use margins, but `position:relative` for the outer div and `position:absolute` for the inner one, with `bottom:0` to position it at the bottom of the outer one.

```css
.art-banner {
  background-image: url("https://photos-2.dropbox.com/t/2/AAAtS4UXAnyf0x4vH0ty5lE779vFfS2smjUWyJFsFwnMPg/12/18401260/jpeg/32x32/1/1437685200/0/2/art_banner.jpg/COyP4wggASACIAMgBCAFIAYgBygBKAIoBw/L9JVtmzn-g-n3CMbDujkZkXxzuwR9ntwvtEoBLNl_4g?size=1024x768&size_mode=2");
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}
.art-banner-text {
  width: 940px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.art-banner-text h2 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-family: "Bender";
  margin: 0;
}
.art-banner-text span {
  color: #eb6623;
}
```

```html
<div class="col_one art-banner">
  <div class="art-banner-text">
    <h2>what do <span>you</span> want to learn?</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

(Note that I had to change the URI for the image, to make it show up. What you had was the URI for the dropbox page that displays the image, not the image itself.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the outer container ( which is .art-banner-text) set to position:relative; and set the inner div or element to absolute to place it where you want. https://jsfiddle.net/2ryrnxz7/

```
<div class="col_one art-banner">
        <div class="art-banner-text">
            <h2>what do <span>you</span> want to learn?</h2>
        </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.art-banner { background-image: url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/migdkqlmse8ym0t/art_banner.jpg?dl=0"); height: 150px;}
.art-banner-text { width: 940px; height: 50px; position: relative; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); }
.art-banner-text h2 { font-family: "Bender"; margin: auto 0; padding:0px; bottom:0px; position:absolute; left:35%}
.art-banner-text span { color: #eb6623; }
```

You can set the left to whatever % you want to push towards the middle. This won't work for mobile as it is set and won't reposition itself with the page. But if you just need it to work for desktop, this is how to do it.

Comment: That moved the text to the bottom of the black container. I am trying to move the text and the black container to the bottom of the image. I dont know why the image is not showing up

Comment: Then switch the position: absolute to the container. I just set it to the h2 because thats what I thought you wanted. So use your original code but switch the div you want to move to absolute with the bottom:0px, left:(whatever you want, I just choose 35%) and make sure it's all wrapped in a container with position:relative

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might want to use CSS positioning. For example `.art-banner {position: relative;} .art-banner-text {position: absolute;}` You can then position, move, or animate the text in the inner div without affecting the outer div.